# Access to rabbitMQ management interface

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-management

I've followed the installation procedure to unlock browser access:

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
sudo chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/
```

After reaching localhost:15672 all I've got is a blank page:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RabbitMQ Management</title>
    <script src="js/ejs-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flot-0.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flot-0.8.1.time.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/sammy-0.7.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/json2-2016.10.28.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/prefs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/formatters.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/charts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="js/excanvas.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/evil.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="outer"></div>
    <div id="debug"></div>
    <div id="scratch"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where's the login form?

Answer (score 0):

ok, adding a few more details: I use vagrant and I want to reach the url from my host machine.
So, after checking server logs the reason for my failure was the missing '/' in virtual host file. So that's the kind of proper one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName rabbit.fbm

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.56.101:15672/

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/rabbit_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/rabbit_access.log" combined

</VirtualHost>
```

P.S. Don't forget about the firewall on your host machine.